# Questions about matrix notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am reading a paper and I have a notation problem, the authors are using the Einstein implicit summation convention for repeated greek indices and write:

$$\phi_{\alpha}(\vec{r}) = \sum_{i} \; \psi_i(\vec{r})M_{i \alpha}$$

$$\psi_{i}(\vec{r}) = \phi_{\alpha}(\vec{r})M_{i}^{\alpha}$$

Where $M$ is a linear transformation.

Why is $\alpha$ is used as subscript and superscript? Could someone clarify the meaning of these two lines?

Comment: The authors are the best reference for what they meant (and "why" they chose that notation), and you have not identified the paper and authors that you are asking about.  You are asking Readers for speculation, since not even the subject matter of the paper is evident from the little you've written.  Context is always important, but never more so than in asking about why authors chose to write an expression as they did.

Comment: Sorry, I tought the authors wrote their article in a way that most people will understand (they are not giving any more explanation on the notation) From my point of view that was just some classic algebra I was not able to understand.

Comment: The [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) applies when an index (variable otherwise not defined) appears both as a subscript and a superscript in an expression.  I'd read the first equation as *defining* an expression that depends on $\alpha$ and the second as defining an expression that depends on $i$.  An explicit summation is used in the first because $i$ does not appear as both subscript and superscript (only as subscripts).  The summation can be elided in the second equation, by that convention.  Need a reference to say more.

Comment: Thank you, the reference is https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/5.0004445 If you have any interesting ressources to help me understand the algebra of this paper please feel free to share it

Comment: It looks evident the contravariant Greek indices indicate an inverse, so, therefore, $M_{j\alpha} M_i^\alpha= \delta_{ji}$, where the Einstein summation convention is used for repeated Greek indices *only*--you can see what they do not wish to apply this to Latin indices! Check out the inter convertibility of the two expressions.